# python import dlib failed with segmentation fault

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, dlib

Now I trying to use dlib with python.
But I get segmentation fault error when import dlib.

I tried with anaconda, virtualenv, and system default.
I tried to install with pip install, conda install, python setup.py.
All of these end up with segmentation fault.

I confirm appropriate python interpreter is used by "which python".

One of the output of lldb is below.
It is with anaconda3 and dlib installed from "python setup.py install"

```
(base) aaaaaaaa@bbbbbbbb:~$ lldb python
(lldb) target create "python"
Current executable set to 'python' (x86_64).
(lldb) launch process
error: 'launch' is not a valid command.
error: Unrecognized command 'launch'.
(lldb) process launch
Process 11896 launched: '/home/aaaaaaaa/anaconda/bin/python' (x86_64)
Python 3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 18:10:19) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dlib
Process 11896 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 11896, 0x00005555556b429d python`PyObject_SetItem + 45, name = 'python', stop reason = signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0x70)
    frame #0: 0x00005555556b429d python`PyObject_SetItem + 45
python`PyObject_SetItem:
->  0x5555556b429d <+45>: movq   0x70(%rbp), %rsi
    0x5555556b42a1 <+49>: testq  %rsi, %rsi
    0x5555556b42a4 <+52>: je     0x5555556b42bd            ; <+77>
    0x5555556b42a6 <+54>: movq   0x10(%rsi), %rax
```

Anyone who knows the cause, and the solution?
Please help me!

Comment: And the OS I use is ubuntu16.04 64bit

Answer (score 1):

I finally did it with venv.
How I did is like below.

1. pip uninstall dlib
2. download dlib source from http://dlib.net/
3. activate venv
4. python setup.py install

May be some kind of library reference relationship was collapsed.